# Программа для выведения графика на c#. Обновление в реальном времени

Tags: c#, winforms, arduino, диаграммы

Есть программа для считывания данных ком порта, их последующую запись в текстовый файл и вывод графика по этим данным. Проблема в том, что она не обновляет график по приходу новых значений в этот текстовый файл. Я пробовал через chart.refresh у меня, к сожалению ничего не вышло...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.IO;

namespace arduino
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            notifyIcon1.Visible = false;
            this.notifyIcon1.MouseClick += new MouseEventHandler(notifyIcon1_MouseClick);
            this.Resize += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_Resize);

            // Открываем порт, и задаем скорость в 9600 бод
            serialPort1.PortName = "COM6";
            serialPort1.BaudRate = 9600;
            serialPort1.DtrEnable = true;
            serialPort1.Open();
            serialPort1.DataReceived += serialPort1_DataReceived;
            serialPort1.DataReceived += serialPort1_DataReceived1;
        }
        //****** поток ком порта
        private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            string vlag = serialPort1.ReadLine();
            this.BeginInvoke(new LineReceivedEvent(LineReceived), vlag);
        }

        private void serialPort1_DataReceived1(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            string temp = serialPort1.ReadLine();
            this.BeginInvoke(new LineReceivedEvent1(LineReceived1), temp);
        }

        //запись влажности
        private delegate void LineReceivedEvent(string vlag);
        private void LineReceived(string vlag)
        {
            textBox1.Text = vlag;
            string path = "График_влажности.txt";
            string date = DateTime.Now.ToString();
            // Создание файла и запись в него
            using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(path))
            {
                sw.WriteLine(vlag);
                sw.WriteLine(date);
            }
        }

        //запись температуры
        private delegate void LineReceivedEvent1(string temp);
        private void LineReceived1(string temp)
        {
            textBox2.Text = temp.ToString();
            string path = "График_температуры.txt";
            string date = DateTime.Now.ToString();
            // Создание файла и запись в него
            using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(path))
            {
                sw.WriteLine(temp);
                sw.WriteLine(date);
            }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.Zoom(0,30);
                chart1.ChartAreas[0].CursorX.IsUserEnabled = true;
                chart1.ChartAreas[0].CursorX.IsUserSelectionEnabled = true;
                chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.Zoomable = true;
                chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScrollBar.IsPositionedInside = true;

                //chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.ScaleView.Zoom(0, 30);
                //chart1.ChartAreas[0].CursorY.IsUserEnabled = true;
                //chart1.ChartAreas[0].CursorY.IsUserSelectionEnabled = true;
                //chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.ScaleView.Zoomable = true;
                //chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.ScrollBar.IsPositionedInside = true;

                StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(openFileDialog1.FileName);
                chart1.Series[0].Points.Clear();
                while (!streamReader.EndOfStream)
                {           
                    string Y = streamReader.ReadLine();
                    string X = streamReader.ReadLine();

                    chart1.Series[0].Color = Color.Red;
                    chart1.Series[0].BorderWidth = 1;
                    chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(X, Y);
                }
                streamReader.Close();
            } 
        }

        private void Form1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
            {
                this.Hide();
                notifyIcon1.Visible = true;
            }
        }

        private void notifyIcon1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Show();
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
            notifyIcon1.Visible = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Проблема - это когда есть код, но он работает не так, как задумано. А у вас кода, который бы автоматом обновлял график нет, ну или я его не вижу, потому и не обновляется

Comment: @tym32167,  Я не силен в C#, поэтому прошу помощи, где и что нужно поправить .

Comment: Ну, по вашему коду и так есть вопросы. Например, какой смысл писать в файл и потом читать его целиком? Может, Вам лучше писать в память, в какую то коллекцию? Ну и у вас же есть код для прорисовки графика, его надо вызвать там, где приходят данные с портов

Comment: @tym32167, писать в файл и потом читать его целиком необходимо для целей самого проекта. Мне просто необходимо обновление графика с приходом новых данных в этот файл. Прошу помощи потому, что необходимо срочно, а как я сказал я не силен в C#, и вопрос жизни и смерти лично для меня...

Comment: Вы видите код, который пишет данные в файл? Вы видите код, который считывает данные из файла и показывает на графике? Вам надо просто считывать график каждый раз после записи. Знаний по C# тут не надо. Единственное, что не понятно - это то, что файла 2, а график то у вас один

Comment: @tym32167, в самом окне программы я выбираю какой график строить, вы можете помочь мне с обновлением или нет?

Comment: Я вам уже помог как смог - комментариями, тут все, что нужно, чтобы решить задачу. Писать код для вас я не буду. Вы можете подождать помощи от другого участника сообщества или можете попробовать решить задачу самостоятельно

Comment: @tym32167, к сожалению я не нашел решения в ваших комментариях, то что вы сказали я и так все знал... Буду ждать другого участника более отзывчивого, который может помочь студенту...

Comment: Чтож, удачи вам. Ну и небольшой совет - если хотите увеличить вероятность ответа от более отзывчивого участника, напишите в вопросе не только постановку задачи, но и как вы сами пробовали её решить. Практика показала, что авторам вопросов, которые сами как то пытаются решить свои проблемы, сообщество помогает более охотно. Это, конечно, ответ не гарантирует, но вероятность, что на вас обратят внимание увеличит.

Comment: @tym32167, я пробовал через chart.refresh ничего не вышло, я все-таки только учусь...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Весь код из метода `button1_Click()`, связанный с построением графика, надо вынести в отдельный метод `private void ShowChart(string filename) {...}`

2) В методе `button1_Click()` надо теперь просто вызвать этот метод с передачей нужного пути к файлу.

```
if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
     ShowChart(openFileDialog1.FileName);
}
```

3) В методах `LineReceived(string vlag)` и `LineReceived1(string temp)` после записи порции данных, вызывать этот же самый метод `ShowChart()` с передачей ему нужного пути к обновленному файлу.